# Как отобразить текст содержащий HTML теги и картинки на iOS Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift

Из `API` я получаю текст содержащую `HTML теги` и `картинки`. Как их правильно отобразить. Пытался с помощью `NSAttributedString`, но это не то что мне нужно. И в чем его отобразить, в `UILabel` или в `WebView`?.

**Платформа iOS 9, Swift 3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось сделать без WebView

В Info.plist сделал разрешение на http:

> App Transport Security Settings -> Allow Arbitrary Loads -> YES

И этот код заработал:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: (self.detailLabelText?.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!)!,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
            documentAttributes: nil)

 self.detailLabel.attributedText = attrStr
 self.detailLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
 self.detailLabel.contentMode = .scaleToFill
 self.detailLabel.font = UIFont(name: "PTSans-Narrow", size: 18.0)
}

detailLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
detailLabel.sizeToFit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите отображать картинки, то `UILabel` Вам не поможет, так как внутри Вы можете отображать только текст. Используйте `UIWevView`.

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: Картинки не показывает

Comment: Значит проблема в HTML коде. Попробуйте открыть ваш HTML код в браузере, и посмотрите, показывает картинки или нет

Comment: App Transport Security Settings настроил теперь открывается

Comment: Если ответ помог, отметьте его как верный